# Node on Windows not showing message if server is already running in port 3000

Tags: node.js

I am studying nodejs and I was following a beginners tutorial.
I followed the instructions and wrote the example code without errors.
When I ran my js file using node it doesn't show or notify if the server is already running on port 3000 like most of the examples do even if it was already running on port 3000.

I then added logging to see if my console was just not displaying log messages from node but it log and displayed properly.

```
console.log('Requested route: ', req.url);
console.log('Requested method: ', req.method);
```

What did I do wrong or what do I have to do so it notifies and displays in the console if the server is already running?  Sometimes I just stare at the screen and not know if the server has already started or it hanged.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is add the console.log call inside of the http.listen block:

```
http.createServer(router).listen(3000, () => {
   console.log('server is running on port 3000');
})
```

Besides that, I really recommend you to move on and use express-js framework. https://expressjs.com/